# How to make video autoplay in a lightbox like on a ClickFunnels page?

Tags: wordpress, video, autoplay, elementor

So I want to make my videos form Vimeo autoplay in a lightbox immediately after user clicks the "preview".

One click on a preview should open a lightbox and start a video autoplay like it's done in a clickfunnels page: https://www.clickfunnels.com/

Right now I need to make two clicks - one to open a lightbox and second to play video. 
I try to add ?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0 to Vimeo videos but it doesn't work.

I'm making a website on a Wordpress using Elementor builder:
http://biznesprzezrekomendacje.pl/

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Some browsers added a policy to only autoplay videos that are muted. Try to add `mute=1`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the param &mute=1 on your link because YouTube doesn't works autoplay on videos with sound.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).